# Conditional expectation using sum formula

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In a 2nd year probability course, I used to calculate conditional expectation $E[N|M]$ this way; first calculate $E[N|M=m]$, call it $f(m)$, then replace little m with big M. Nice and easy, (at least theoretically). Now in a 3rd year stochastic modelling course, I am given this formula to calculate conditional expectation which, it is said, is the reason why we could do the above. $$ E[N|M]= \sum_{i}E[N|M=m_i]\mathbb{1}_{M=m_i}$$

The steps to calculate conditional expectation using this formula would be to first calculate $f(m)$, replace m with big M, take $f(M)$ out of the sum and say that $\sum_{i}\mathbb{1}_{M=m_i}$ sums to 1. Could someone explain to me why we can replace little m with big M after calculating $f(m)$ and why the sum of indicators sum to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $\sum_i1_{M=m_i} = 1$ because exactly one of the indicators in the sum is $1$ and others are $0$.

For basically the same reason you can replace $m$ with $M$.

Suppose we have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.

Now, in your formula:
\begin{align}
E[N\mid M] &= \sum_{i}E[N\mid M=m_i]\mathbb{1}_{M=m_i},
\end{align}
for each given $\omega \in \Omega$, we have that $M=M(\omega)=m_k$ for exactly one $k$, obviously, and only that indicator is $1$ and others are $0$. Thus, for $\omega$, the sum becomes
\begin{align}
\sum_{i}E[N\mid M=m_i]\mathbb{1}_{M=m_i} = E[N\mid M=m_k] = f(m_k) = f(M(\omega)).
\end{align}

So the variable $E[N\mid M]$ is a mapping $\omega \mapsto f(M(\omega))$.

---

As for replacing $m$ with $M$ right at the start and taking it out of the sum, I don't think that's a valid way as you don't really have a common factor to take out of the sum - each $E[N\mid M=m_i] = f(m_i)$ is different. You need the indicators to leave only one summand and then you can see that replacement is ok to do, as we have shown.